# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Photoshop to select the lowest layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shortcuts

The scenario is that i have 7 different layers and obviously, my screen monitor can't show them all (just only five layers). If i select the upper-most layer(the layer panel will adjust up) then I want to switch select the lower-most layer, is there shortcut key for it? Thanks.

Btw, the lower-most layer is locked.

Gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoTg0.jpg

Comment: it is same as windows select command. you know ctrl click for non contiguous thing and shift click for contiguous one.

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin No. I mean, i''m not adding, but changing my selection.

Comment: you mean stacking orders of layers??

Comment: i mean at first layer 1 then the lower most? (u want it to be 2nd layer)???

Comment: changing my selection-- what it implies?

Comment: @Suraiya Abedin Sorry if my english is bad, but take a look with my example.

Comment: You can increase the size of the layer tab by (in your case) bringing the mouse pointer between the layer tab and the swatches tab (the one with all the colors) and then click and drag up. This way you'll at least be able to see all your layers without having to scroll to click the bottom one. If you're not using it, you can even close the swatches tab to give yourself even more room for your layers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are shortcuts for selecting the first and the last layer.

- `Alt + .` → Top layer
- `Alt + ,` → Bottom layer

[Photoshop default keyboard shortcuts](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

---

There's also a shortcut for selecting the next layer above and below: `Alt + [` and `Alt + ]`.

---

Additionally, there are ways to select layers from the document, which I'm a big fan of. Just point at a layer in the document and click... Especially handy if you're terrible at organizing layers in the layers panel by grouping and naming. Though you probably won't have that issue with just <10 layers.

**The `Move tool` has this option called `Auto-select`:**

1. When this setting is on, you can `Left click` layers or groups depending on the selection in the dropdown that follows it.
2. You can also then `click + drag` to select multiple layers.
3. Locked layers are ignored.
4. There's also the `Right click` context menu way of selection layers
5. You can toggle the `Auto-select` option by holding down `Ctrl` (I usually turn the setting off and enable it with Ctrl when needed)
6. Using `Shift` modifier with this method allows you to add/remove layers from the selection. So with the auto-select off, the modifier key combination would be: `Ctrl + Shift + Left Click`

**The method I use the most is `Ctrl + Alt + Right click`:**

1. This works similar to the move tool methods, but there are a few differences.
2. You don't have to have a specific tool selected to use this. That said I believe there are some tools that won't let you use it, if I'm remembering that correctly.
3. This method will select locked layers
4. Doesn't select groups
5. No context menu option
6. No click and drag
7. Using `Shift` modifier with this method allows you to add/remove layers from the selection: `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Right click`

> Switch all `Ctrl` modifiers with `Cmd` on Mac.

Comment: Interesting I was unaware of the top/bottom options.

Comment: @Scott, just like shortcuts for selecting the next layer, these two are also pretty well hidden. I believe you can find them in some helpx article, but they are nowhere to be seen in PS and these shortcuts can't be changed either.

Comment: Noi on aika vaikeita suomalaisessa näppiksessä

Comment: @joojaa, jep. Paras tapa ratkasta tää ongelma on nauhottaa scripta scripting listerenillä käyttäen US näppis layouttia. Tosin vaikka mulla on vuosia ollu pikanäppäimet niille toiminnoille tehty tällä tavalla, niitä ei vaan tuu käytettyä :/

Comment: To find these shortcut open the adobe cc launcher and search for 'keyboard shortcuts photoshop'. Then, scroll down 'til you see the section 'Use the Layers Panel'

Comment: @Scott Why do you deleted your comment? I didn't see your reply.

Comment: @Joonas Thanks very much! Your method using the Move Tool doesn't work, as I stated, the layer that I want to switch selection is locked. But your first answer works fine as stated in my problem.

Comment: @nocturns2, are you sure about that? I assume you meant: Open Photoshop CC and go to `Edit > Keyboard shortcuts` and then find `Use the layers panel` there, but I couldn't find it. Every time I look for these things, I click the summarize button to print out a html file and even in there I still couldn't find them with the browsers page searching. I tried looking for it online, but I only [found an article for PS Elements](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/keys-layers-panel.html) that mentions these shortcuts.

Comment: @FernanBuan, just in case you missed it, the second document selection method (last one in the answer) `Ctrl + Alt + Right click` selects locked layers too.

Comment: @FernanBuan because Joonas proved me wrong `:)`

Comment: https://media.tenor.com/images/cdbec141b2abfe1e8e113009b0037927/tenor.gif

Comment: @Joonas, yes, I meant the adobe cc launcher (aka, adobe cc app). It contains all your available adobe apps, (i.e., photoshop, illustrator, InDesign, etc...) that you can run. Enter your search in the launcher's search bar. It will open a browser with the shortcuts for, in this case photoshop. You would be looking for info only. If you're looking to change shortcut key, then, you would go to the program and change the settings.

Comment: @nocturns2, right... I was really confused. At first I thought you were just kinda saying it broadly like "whatever adobe cc app it is... you'll find it in the keyboard shortcuts...". How dumb I was. Though I should point out that it simply searches the helpx website. That said, I was able to find the shortcuts through it and this is indeed the page I've seen before, with the mentioned shortcuts included: [Photoshop default keyboard shortcuts](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html).

Comment: @Joonas hahahaha you ate Scott alive with your gif. Kek'ed.

Answer (score 2):

For this exact scenario you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> — that is a shortcut for `Select Next Layer` but if you have the top layer selected it'll jump back to the first one. The same is true for opposite: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> will select top layer if you have the first selected.

Comment: Thank you very much  for your answer. Yes i'm doing this (before joonas answered) Now I prefer using Alt +,

Comment: @FernanBuan I agree, that answer is far more comprehensive. I didn't know about that shortcut either!

Comment: I wish these hotkeys let me traverse items within a layer group.

Answer (score -3):

For mac keyboards it is " **Alt + :** " and " **Alt + =** "

Comment: no it's not. I tried in both my MacBook Pro keyboard and the wireless keyboard, these are the wrong shortcuts.

Comment: On Mac, it's exactly as the accepted answer states, alt comma or stop.

Comment: Without knowing what keyboard or layout this guy is using I have to admit that maybe this answer is a bit too vague and misleading, but it does bring up a good point. I just wanted to give some insight on this. It's possible this guy has a _weird_ keyboard or maybe he is using the US layout in a non-US keyboard. As an example, in my Fin/Swe keyboard with  the US layout, the top and bottom layer shortcuts are the same, but the next layer up or down is `Alt+Å` and `Alt+^. If I use my Finnish layout, however, the next layer up or down no longer works. As far as I know, there is no way to

Comment: invoke any square bracket shortcut in my Fin/Swe keyboard. I believe many Europeans have this issue with Adobe application shortcuts that use square brackets and possibly some other keys. Which is infuriating because some of those shortcuts in PS can't be changed. I believe selecting the next layer down or up is one of those. You can get past the issue by changing the keyboard layout to US, which is something I do occasionally when I'm making actions. Any other time I want to use these shortcuts I use a script that I've recorder with scripting listener + the US layout.